# Harry Potter fanfic where Harry argues with Voldemort over a wizard radio interview

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I can only remember a certain part of it where Harry argues with Voldemort over a wizard radio interview. I also remember that he goes to this master duelist to train. There is another scene I remember where he duels three people at a tournament thing. I believe it was at Hogwarts. One of the people he was dueling turned into a animal and bit him. When he won he made sparks come out of his wand in Gryffindor colors. Harry is also in a relationship with Draco. There are plenty of original characters in this story as well. I don't think in this fanfic he is at the best terms with Dumbledore. I read this story back in 2015 or 14.

Comment: Mod note: suggested edit was approved since it appears to be the OP.

Comment: Do you remember what site you read this on or how long ago you read this?